# Unix and Linux Cut command to equivalent with the For Loop DOS command

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, command, cut

**Scenario**

I have this OpenSSL command with an output to a pipe for a cut.

```
openssl x509 -serial -noout -in cacert.pem | cut -d= -f2 > serial
```

**I would like to keep only the serial number but with loop for cmd**

```
openssl x509 -serial -noout -in cacert.pem
serial=E314E555E2D52FC8
```

**Example of the result I hope**

```
openssl x509 -serial -noout -in cacert.pem | FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %G IN ("pipe=result") DO @echo %G>serial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOS doesn't have a FOR loop like the one you're trying, but I suspect you don't mean DOS as OpenSSL has not been ported to that operating system. If you mean Windows, then the command you need is:

```
(for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('openssl x509 -serial -noout -in cacert.pem') do @echo %a) > serial
```

If you put the above in a .bat file, you'll need to change `%a` to `%%a`.

Comment: Effectively, as you say very well, it is about windows. The correct answer you gave me solves my problem. Thank You